# ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.38 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall

I have installed openssh server on my system using the following command:

> apt-get install openssh-server

But when I tried to remotely access this server from another system (client) it shows me an error:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.38 port 22: Connection refused.

Can you please help me find whether the port is open or not?

Taken from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743559/ssh-connect-to-host-192-168-1-38-port-22-connection-refused

Comment: Very similar http://superuser.com/questions/368333/ssh-connection-refused?rq=1

Comment: Have you verified that the server is actually running? Run `sudo service ssh status` to find out.

Comment: And did you actually try any of the fine solutions offered in the other question?

Comment: Good point. Maybe it was not the best idea to repost the question instead of OP (from SO). I don't have this problem. But a typical set of checks should be useful for other users of SU. So I guess the question itself and all the answers are still valid. Maybe  something better would be to close this question and make a wiki question out of referred older one?

Comment: As the question currently stands, you say that you installed the SSH server on a a computer ("PC1", let's say), and when you try to access a _remote_ system ("PC2"), you got the response that there was no SSH server active at PC2. I'm guessing it's just a phrasing problem, and that you are actually trying to access PC1, not PC2, but it would be good to clarify that. Also, more information on the remote system would be good: are you trying to access it across a NAT, or are both systems within the same network? Edit the question to clarify these points.

Comment: Note it is not my question originally

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be coming from firewall or may be coming from SElinux or may be service not in running state.
I'm not aware  from your distribution but i will told you for RPM based & debian OS : 
For RPM based OS

For flush firewall command

> iptable -F

For disable SElinux

> setenforce 0

For start the service

> service sshd restart

If you are using Debian based OS then just follow these steps :
for installation

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client

To restart ssh server, enter:

> sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart

Answer (score 1):

What is your distribution?

It might be a firewall problem. On ubuntu check

> sudo ufw status

In general use telnet client to test tcp connection

> telnet  192.168.1.38 22

(Expect to see some welcome message from OpenSSH for default settings)

or network scanners like nmap on your client-side:

> nmap 192.168.1.38 -p 22

Finally check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config as well as if the sshd daemon is running

> ps aux | grep sshd